# I want to take two integer numbers in one row and calculate their sum in python3

Tags: python-3.x, split

I want to take two numbers in one row by space and get their sum. 
so I think I have to use a split()

This is the code I wrote

```
    num1,num2 = map(int,input.split())
    result = num1+num2
    print(str(result))
```

'''It keep says that this code have a runtime error but I can't find out why'''

Comment: `input().split()`.

Comment: Also, `print(result)`.  `str()` is unnecessary.

Comment: The actual error is `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'`.  `input` is a function.  You have to call it (`input()`) to get the string result that has a `.split()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the fact that you're calling ".split()" on "input" which is a function. If you want to apply the "split()" to the RESULT of the "input" function, you should write it as "input().split()".

Plus, if you want to allow only one or more than 2 numbers, you should consider using the sum() function of python.

Finally the str(result) is not needed as print() will already try to format it's parameter as a string.

Here is your version fixed (by adding the missing "()"):

```
num1, num2 = map(int, input().split())
result = num1 + num2
print(result)
```

And here is a version using the function "sum()":

```
values = map(int, input().split())
my_sum = sum(values)
print(my_sum)
```